# Multiple definitions to include function call without square brackets

Tags: function-construction

I'd like to have a function that returns elements of a matrix:

```
MATR = Table[i + j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}];
ff[a_,b_] := MATR[[a,b]];
```

I can make second  definition with no arguments. In this case function returns entire matrix in `MatrixForm`:

```
ff[] := MatrixForm[MATR];
```

I wonder if it possible to make a definition that makes no use of square brackets at all and does the same thing. I know this will go into `OwnValues` rather than `DownValues`. So if I just make

```
ff := MatrixForm[MATR];
```

then `ff` returns `MatrixForm[MATR]`, but `ff[1,1]` does not work any more, it returns entire matrix in `MatrixForm` followed by `[1,1]`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Might be a problem. A definition like `ff[a_, b_] := (* stuff *)` stores to `DownValues[ff]`, while a definition like `ff := (* stuff *)` stores to `OwnValues[ff]`.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to try something like that, even if it was possible. Better assign key short cuts for `[[` and `]]`. Have a look for `KeyEventTranslations.tr`.